# Javascript - cleaning a string with str.replace()

Tags: javascript

I have a URL that can be divided in 3 parts and I want the middle one.

The URL is like this

http://www.site.com/place?siteurl=**http://www.thisIsWhatIwant.com/bla/bla/**&XXX

XXX means that the URL continues and may have a lot of characters including %, parenthesis, other ampersands, equal signs, etc...

I want what is in bold. I other words, to get rid of everything that is before the equal sign on siteurl= (including the equal sign) and also get rid of everything that is after the first ampersand after that, including the ampersand... so, after cleaning the URL it would become just:

**http://www.thisIsWhatIwant.com/bla/bla/**

how do I do that with Javascript's str.replace()?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use `String.replace` here, use `String.split`:

```
if(window.location.search.indexOf('siteurl') > -1) {
   var siteurl = window.location.search.split('siteurl=')[1];
   siteurl = siteurl.substring(0, siteurl.indexOf('&'));
   //do something with siteurl...
} else {
   //siteurl is not in the URL.
}
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want anything after the first "&" either.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than remove the text you don't want, you can extract the text you *do* want using `String.match()`:

```
var s = "http://www.site.com/place?siteurl=http://www.thisIsWhatIwant.com/bla/bla/&XXX";
var middle = s.match(/siteurl\=(.*?)\&/i)[1];
```